# Is there a Boot-Repair for Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 15.04, boot-repair

While trying to change my computer's default boot loader, I have run into the obstacle of having the message `E: unable to locate package boot-repair`. I learned that this could be because Boot-Repair does not have an update for Ubuntu 15.04, but could not find any information to validate my suspicions. I've tried many different commands to attempt to fix this, but none have worked.

Comment: It does exist, but 15.04 is no longer supported, and the URLs for its PPAs have been moved to archive mirrors, meaning the ones Ubuntu is looking at don't exist. You also don't get security updates. You should really upgrade to a supported release of Ubuntu, such as 15.10 or 16.04.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

Answer (score 0):

You can attempt to add the Boot-Repair ppa by issuing the commands

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
```

If you get `404 Not Found` messages and an error `Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.`
 that tells you that the ppa does not exist for your release.